# Algorithms: distribute elements far away from each other

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an array of sorted integers. Given an integer N i need to place N largest elements further away from each other so that they have maximum space between each other. The remaining elements should be placed between these big items. For example, array of 10 with N=3 would result in [0, 5, 8, 2, 6, 9, 3, 7, 10, 4].

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] start = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int[] end = new int[10];
    int N = 4;
    int step = Math.round(start.length / N );
    int y = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j<start.length; j = j + step) {
            //System.out.println(j + " " + i);
            if (count < start.length && start[count] != 0) {
                end[j] = start[count];
                count++;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(end.toString());

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. Show what you have tried and then the community will help you understand where you went wrong.

Comment: Why not `[8,0,1,2,3,9,4,5,6,7,10]` then? Do you use circular indexing?

Comment: Array[0] is the largest number and array is sorted in descending order.

Comment: @Sean pls see above my code in Java

Comment: @Angelina, well, this solution can't deal with zeroes. And its complexity is n squared.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of `K` elements. You have `N` max numbers you need to distribute. Then:

1. `Step := K/N` (removing the remainder)
2. Take any number from `N` maximum and insert it at `Step/2` position.
3. Take other maximum numbers and insert it after the previous inserted maximum number at `Step` distance.

Giving `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. So `K = 10`, `N = 3`. Then `Step = 3`. So the first maximum is placed at `3/2` position

`[1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Then other `2` are put at `3` distance from each other:

`[1,10,2,3,9,4,5,8,6,7]`

The code:

```cpp
std::vector<int> Distribute(std::vector<int> aSource, int aNumber)
{
    auto step = aSource.size() / aNumber; // Note integer dividing.
    for (int i = 0; i < aNumber; ++i)
    {
        auto place = aSource.end() - i * step - step / 2;
        aSource.insert(place, aSource.front());
        aSource.erase(aSource.begin());
    }
    return aSource;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10};
    auto res = Distribute(vec, 4);
    for (auto e : res)
    {
        std::cout << e << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
6, 5, 4, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0, 8, -1, -2, -3, -4, 9, -5, -6, -7, -8, 10, -9, -10,
```

Comment: step/2 would not give integer and it is needed to be an index of an array

Comment: @Angelina, as I pointed it in the post, remainder is not used.

Comment: where is 2 coming from in `Step/2`? why 2?

Comment: @Angelina, not 2. It's 1. And in programming we usually start to count from 0.

Comment: really funny! LOL

Comment: @Angelina Oh, sorry. I didn't get you. 2 is because we'd like to place big numbers at some extent from borders. Circular indexing seems to be using as dasblinkenlight supposed. You didn't answer his question.

Comment: i am new to this topic. I am not familiar with circular sorting. Is it sorting used in LinkedLists? I tried to google this term and did not find many relevant articles? What is the official name of this circular algorithm?

Comment: @Angelina, I mean, 2 is about the two halves of the distance from 10 to 8 in your example, if the array was joined by its endings to circle. Like 10, then 4, then 0, then 8.

Comment: @NuPogodi, sorry, i did not understand your solution. I have posted code above (edited question), can you please comment if it is correct, good, etc? feel free to criticize. thanks

Comment: @Angelina, I updated the post with code. Try to conceive.